# realm file size increased dramatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I am currently experiencing the problem where my realm file size is massive. If I comment out the API calls, which in turn inserts data into Realm to have them run one at a time, the file size is roughly 1 MB. However, if I call all of them asynchronously in background threads (since they do not relate to each other), the file size is 16 MB. Any ideas on how to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

This is an inherent part of Realm's functionality. As you're manipulating data inside Realm, it doesn't work to reclaim disk space after the fact. This is because doing so is a costly operation in terms of performance, and without context, potentially of no benefit.

Issues arising from this behaviour in conjunction with very large datasets has been discussed on the Realm GitHub before (https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1159). The Realm Cocoa engineers and the engineers in charge of Realm's internal engine are aware of this issue and are exploring ways to try and find a nice compromise in making the system smarter, without introducing a performance overhead.

In the meantime, I'd recommend don't worry about it unless it actually hits a filesize you deem unacceptable. If that becomes the case, you can use `[RLMRealm writeCopyToPath:error:]` to explicitly generate a copy of the the Realm that will have all of the extra space reclaimed and swap it into the old one's place.

Comment: Thank you for answer. So wouldn't this just build up very quickly? I've only inserted less than 2000 records and the file is at 23 MB. I can't imagine what it will be like when it gets put into production. Are there any ETAs as to when this limitation will be resolved?

Comment: I have been trying your proposed workaround and I am unable to reliably open the realm file using the same encryptionKey of the original file. I am currently using 0.98.0 framework. Any ideas as to why this might be the case?

Comment: I tried this suggestion, but without the encryption on and it works fine. Is there something wrong specifically with the encryption version?

Comment: Uh-oh. If you can't actually open the new file with the encryption key, that might be indicative of a bug. I might recommend taking this issue to https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues to follow that up!

Comment: Got it. I've been assigned to it now! Hmm, I'm not sure why that one went unanswered for long one. I'll follow it up!